# OneToMany Relation not returning all values in db

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have two entries (OrderProduct) in the database pointing at the same parent (ShopOrder) entry.
But when I fetch the parent entry it only contains one of the child entries in the @OneToMany List.
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

ShopOrder DBO
[image: ShopOrder DBO]

ProductOrder entries in the DB
[image: ProductOrder in DB]

Getting the ShopProducts
[image: Getting all ShopProducts]

What I'm getting out of the DB
[image: Display of output]

I'll gladly provide more info/code snippets if necessary.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Small suggestions: if you haven't already I would change the joincolumn name of `shopUser` in `ShopOrder` class to `shop_user_id` and I would recommend you to second guess using `FetchType.EAGER` on `orderProducts` you can always choose to fetch that collection but if you set it to `EAGER` it will always be fetched and you do not have the option anymore to not fetch it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mapped the wrong field.
I should've mapped it by the foreign key instead of id.

[image: Correct mapping]